# Isometric character from 3D blender model

Tags: camera, blender, isometric

I am trying to make a character for an isometric game from a 3D model in Blender. I managed to create a simple humanoid model and implement an isometric camera, rotated by 60° on the x-axis and 45° on the z-axis. Following a screenshot of this model with camera settings:

[image]

I chose making a 3D model in blender because I want to be able to make changes to my models without having to change loads of images or sprite sheets and I also wanted to get into 3D modelling.

I looked into articles by clint bellanger - that's where I got the idea to make my graphics in blender, rather than draw in Illustrator or photshop - but I am not sure how I should continue now. My questions are

- is this a good way to accomplish my goal of making an isometric character from a 3d model
- if it is feasible to turn around the ratio of 2:1 between width and height for my character or if I should render it another way
- if the settings of the camera I have in blender are correct to use for an isometric game with a 2:1 ratio of width and height for the tiles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. The lack of attention showed to this question is precisely that it is not in Q&A format. Title is not a question and you include three different questions at the end. A common error is to use this site as a forum. Try to find a question that leave place to produce a answer that can validate all you have now, that is, if I understood correctly, what you intent.

Comment: Also, have you checked these? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74504/how-can-i-generate-isometric-sprite-sheets-from-3d-animations/81780#81780 https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/how-should-i-set-camera-in-blender-for-example-to-render-a-sprite-which-can-be-u And yes, I don't have statistics of real games to share now, but 2:1 should be the most common setup. I have done it to simplify math. In your 2d render engine, using simple math and pre rendered assets you can match what a true 3d engine would do with a lot of matrix-vector math.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked at the provided articles...the first one i didn't see yet and it is pretty much what i was looking for. I am still just figuring things out so sometimes I don't really know how to ask or what i was really asking for. The first article you linked shed some light on how i should proceed